# How to make my flutter application changes go live directly without pushing a new version update?

Tags: flutter

Does flutter allows us to push live updates without updating the app through play store or app store?
I have a built flutter application and I frequently do to it changes by adding new announcements and pictures. However, when i do these changes they don’t appear on the app that has been already launched on the play store and nothing appears to the users. So what can I do to change this and to make any change I do to directly go live. Other than pushing a new version update everytime as this isn’t reliable at all.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data from a backend instead of uploading new assets to the app every time. If you do that you will need to release updates for the app all the time + the app bundle size will be much bigger. It's basically just not how it is supposed to be done.

A backend is something like an online "storage" for your app's data.

If you don't already know how to build APIs you can also use [Fireabse](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview) which is more beginner-friendly. If you do know python for example you could use [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). More on backends [here](https://www.upwork.com/resources/beginners-guide-back-end-development)

Comment: Can you please tell me more about how to use firebase? Realtime database better or Remote Config?